# The @ symbol in java

Tags: java

What exactly does `@Object.field` do? I was reading some code that i fetched from a decompiler. It uses

```
@Object.name(field = "stuff",field = "stuff")
public static Object fieldName;
```

Comment: Refer to [Lesson: Annotations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/).

Comment: Just what i was looking for.

Comment: I am pretty sure the above is not syntacticaly correct as multiple values for field ie array would be two curly braces.

Comment: `@` is the last refuge of scoundrels.  (I'm pretty sure it says that in The Devils Dictionary.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The @ symbol specifies the **[Annotation types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/declaring.html)**. This represents some metadata associated to your code

> The at sign character (@) indicates to the compiler that what follows
>   is an annotation.